# Is there a noun(phrase) for a force that upsets a given equilibrium, or creates a state of imbalance?

Tags: single-word-requests

Iran's possession of a nuclear weapon 'will surely upset the equilibrium of power.'

I need to replace the verb phrase with a noun/noun phrase.

Comment: Hi, & welcome to EL&U.

Comment: Depending on your meaning, "tipping point" might work.  It is a phrase that is perhaps over-used.

Comment: @MichaelOwenSartin - might be too limited culturally as well.

Comment: @Susan, I absolutely take your point.  I'll be glad when I no longer hear 'tipping point,' but I thought it might serve a purpose here.  If OP wants to use it he needs to see the good definition here:  Tipping point  --  the critical point in a situation, process, or system beyond which a significant and often unstoppable effect or change takes place from   http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/tipping%20point

Answer (score 4):

Iran's possession of a nuclear weapon will be a [destabilising force](https://www.google.com/webhp?hl=all#hl=en&q=%22destabilising+force%22).

> The Spread of Nuclear Weapons in the Middle East: “more may be ...
>   current unipolar structure the spread of such weapons is a major
>   destabilising force. . . ."

Answer (score 0):

[Perturb](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/perturb) works:

> 1:  to cause to be worried or upset :  disquiet
>   2:  to throw into confusion :  disorder
>   3:  to cause to experience a perturbation

Nontechnically, the word might seem a little extreme for your purpose, but there is a technical extension that'll allow for more precise implications on your part: [Perturbation theory](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perturbation_theory).

Comment: Trying to tie in perturbation theory is probably a stretch -- a perturbation in this case is a small displacement that causes a small effect.

Comment: Sure, but 'destabilizing' for example implies the system is prone to catastrophe. Most systems when poked, reach at worst a slightly changed steady state, or 'equilibrium' in the common parlance.

Comment: I was under the impression that OP wanted a word that implied exactly the opposite -- they specifically say that the equilibrium will be upset.